# TDD: suitability of a testcase

Tags: java, junit, tdd

I am starting with TDD and JUnit. After checking tutorials and docs I have some questions and would be happy if I get some best practice feedback.

**A)** All examples I saw are for methods that have a sort of semantic/logic.

input -> logic -> output

e.g. 2 numbers -> add them -> result

The testcase checks the logic because of the transformation of input to output.
I understand that and its fine.

What if there is no such input (or there is a big dependency on external results)?

e.g.

```
String getName (int id)
{
  // read the name of a staffmember out of the DB and return it
}
```

I see no real logic there that can be checked context-independent at compile/deploy time.

What assert would make sense or is that a sample where no test would be fair?

I think only tests for contextual independent input would make sense. A external database or the result of a webrequest is that not (I think - do you agree?).

**B)** What do you guys think is the ratio of "methods exist" to "methods with a testcase"? Sure that depends on the project or the topic but I would be interested in some numbers.

Comment: **A**: What may happen when you execute your example method? There may be no staff member with the given id, which is worth being tested (does it `return null` or throw an `Exception`?). There could be problems with the database connection (server offline/shutdown, client not online...), which should be tested (you could assert some `Exception` in that case). There may be even more...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, while most functions can have tests, not all functions need to be tested directly. Some are better tested by a test of the calling code.

Second, when dealing with side effects or code that relies on state, there are ways to create the context you require for testing a certain scenario. One of the ways is using [test doubles](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html).

Of course we need to have tests for code that isn't pure functions. You can minimize the amount of code you have that isn't pure functions (e.g. using Functional Programming), but if you don't, the rest of your code needs to be tested as well.

Lastly, the "ratio" you're talking about, or "test coverage" as it is usually called, depends on the level of confidence you have in your test suite. In the end, it is that confidence that allows you to refactor your code without fear of breaking things, which, in the end, is the whole point.

Answer (score 3):

As deHaar pointed out in his comment there are many edge cases that you want to cover. When testing the db the following can be done:

- You mock the Database (in a Spring project your repository), and configure it to return / throw. Then in your test you test stuff like: `givenNoCustomerInDB_thenNotFoundExceptionThrownIsWrappedToXXX()`. Here you would test that the service method that calls the DB catches the exception and wraps it accordingly. For this approach you might want to look up Mockito, the "de facto" mocking framework for Java.
- Another option is to have an in-memory database (H2 for example) that is used when doing the tests.

One thing to keep in mind: You are the responsible for making sure that the mocks (or H2) behaves as your real DB. @Kraylog suggests integration tests for writing adapters to IO devices, and Contract Tests for making sure a mock behaves the same way.

Comment: Using manual tests to see that mocks behave as the real thing isn't good enough. We use Integration Tests for writing adapters to IO devices, and Contract Tests for making sure a mock behaves the same way. The problem with the manual way is that you can't run it in a build. What happens when something changes?

Comment: Good insight! Thanks! I will correct the answer. Thank you @Kraylog

Answer (score 1):

In a test that isolates the test subject from its usual environment, you are going to see the `input -> logic -> output` pattern frequently, because the input data has to be provided by the environment, and the test *is* the environment that the subject experiences.

`TDD` uses isolated tests very often; they are typically both fast and embarrassingly parallel, which means that running them during the design phase has low opportunity cost.

```
String getName (int id)
{
    // read the name of a staffmember out of the DB and return it
}
```

In an example like this one, we would normally be driven toward a design where "the" database is configurable, and in our test we would provide our in-memory database pre-loaded to the correct state.

```
// Copy input to database
// connect test subject to database
// invoke query, thereby retrieving the output
```

It's the same pattern, just carved up differently.

In *many* cases, we can introduce into our design some abstraction for the database, and make that abstraction, rather than the database, the configured dependency.  So rather than using an abstraction that talks to a database, we might instead have a much simpler implementation that is hard coded to return some value.

Such a thing is sometimes known as a [test double](https://martinfowler.com/bliki/TestDouble.html).

```
// Use the input to initialize the test double
// connect test subject to test double
// invoke query, thereby retrieving the output
```

Again, the same pattern appears, the details of the "logic" change somewhat.

The `logic` of `input -> logic -> output` isn't necessarily your production code.  It's common to write tests that integrate with a facade that coordinates the interaction protocol between the test subject and its (doubled) dependencies.

(Tests, just like production code, have design -- investing in a good design now may yield significant profit over the lifetime of the test).